# Is it possible to manage userprofiles in azure AD by c#?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, office365, azure-active-directory

I have a office 365 with about 120 Users in it.

Over the time it comes around that the userproperties (adress and so on) would not be filled properly.
Is it possible to change this in a central position with c# and some csom.

Or alternatively with azure ad (it's connected with this)? And how?

I find nothing about this in google. 
I found only solutions to update own properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an application that can update all user (and group) properties that are stored in Azure AD through the Azure AD Graph API.  You can either use direct calls to the REST API or use the c# and the .Net client library.
For more information I would recommend looking at Azure AD graph API on MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/hh974476.aspx and the new blog on the Graph Client library here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aadgraphteam/archive/2014/12/12/announcing-azure-ad-graph-api-client-library-2-0.aspx which also links to some sample code on github.

Unfortunately I don't think you'll be able to call CSOM through this mechanism, but hopefully this will be a start for you.  Let me know if there's anything else that's not covered by these 2 links.

Hope this helps,